# How to introduce a line break dynamically in the cell for "Link to Documentation"?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

The URL inside "Link to documentation" should go into the next line but despite having overflow warp, the text ends in  the cell but does not enter the next line.

Could you someone please advise me on how to accomplish it ?

Thanks in advance.

```
 <style>
            @page{
                size: A4 portrait;
                margin: 1.5cm;
            }
    
            table {
                border-collapse: separate;
                width: 100%;
                border-spacing: 0;
                table-layout:fixed;
                /* -fs-table-paginate: paginate; */
    
            }
            td {
                /* margin-top: 5px; */
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 5px;
                min-height: 20px;
                /*min-width: 10%;*/
                max-width: 200px;
                overflow: hidden;
                overflow-wrap: break-word;
                /* page-break-inside: avoid; */
            }
            tr{
                margin-top: 5px;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                -fs-keep-with-inline: keep;
            }
    </style>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     Name:
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    Name
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Unit:
                </td>
                <td>
                    Unit
                </td>
                <td>
                    Date:
                </td>
                <td>
                    Date
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Domain
                </td>
                <td>
                    Domain
                </td>
                <td>
                    Subdomain
                </td>
                <td>
                    Subdomain
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Answer to Customer
                </td>
                <td>
                    Answer to customer
                </td>
                <td>
                    Business Line Number
                </td>
                <td>
                    Business Line Number
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Link to Documentation
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <span>  www.google.comwww.google.comwww.google.comwww.google.comwww.google.cwww.google.comwww.google.comwww.google.comwww.google.comwww.google.comwww.google.comwww.google.comwww.google.comgoogle.comgoogle.comgoogle.comgoogle.comgoogle.com
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```